# Where is this Ramban

Tags: sources-mekorot

> יש מקומות שנוהנים לשחוט תרנגול לכפרה וכן יש בתשובת הגאונים המרדכי במס' יומא כתב המנהג הזה וכל מ"ש בסימן זה הוא בפסקי הרא"ש למסכת יומא וקצתו במרדכי ומנהג זה כתוב גם בתשב"ץ וכ' שם שנוהגים ליקח תרנגול לזכר ותרנגולת לנקיבה : והרשב"א כתב בתשוב' בענין הכפרה שעושין לנערי' בעי"ה מנהג זה פשוט בעירנו אע"פ ששמעתי מפי אנשים הגונים מאשכנז שכל רבני ארצם עושים כן וגם שמעתי שנשאל רבינו האיי ואמר שכן נהגו עכ"ז מנעתי המנהג הזה מעירנו וכתוב בא"ת שהרמב"ן אוסרו משום דרכי האמורי :

https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Yosef,_Orach_Chaim_605.1.1

Can anyone help me out with the sources for the meforashim listed here?
I'm specifically interested in the ramban.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think we have it anywhere in writing from the Ramban himself.

Beit Yosef tells you his source:

> כתוב בא"ח שהרמב"ן אוסרו
>
> It's written in Orchot Chaim that Ramban forbade it

The reference is to [Orchot Chaim (of R. Aharon HaKohen of Luneil), Hilchot Erev Kippurim 1](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40307&st=&pgnum=240&hilite=).